# Tcs3200 en el ESP32 con microPython

Tags: esp32, micropython

Alguien tiene un código para programar el sensor de color Tcs3200 en el ESP32 con microPython?

Ya tengo todos los pines conectados a la protoboard pero no me quiere dar el codigo para que el sensor capture bien los datos